# How to resolve CORS issue in real device?

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, cors, ionic4

I'm Developing an android app using Ionic. I'm Calling some API's as data provider. While calling API's we are getting CORS error even on the real device to solve this we have used a proxy. After add proxy API's work fine with the web browser but not with the real device.

```
"proxies": [{
"path": "/api",
"proxyUrl": "http://192.168.43.221:9090/api"
}]
```

> Now this changed my origin to localhost:8080 e.g. the URL http://192.168.43.221:9090/api/getvisitorcount is converted into
>    http://localhost:8080/api/getvisitorcount

Comment: Do not use proxies if you are running app on real device.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Ionic is only for the programming of the `client side`, the configuration of the cors middleware is established on the `server side` and depends on the laguage, framework, library, etc. you are using for.

On your http calls you are limited to add some options like *headers*.

```
const headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': token
});
const options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers
});
this.http.post(url, query, options).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: I used an extension that enables CORS in the browser and everything works fine. How come this is possible if this is a server side problem?

Comment: Check this out https://fullstack-developer.academy/what-is-cors/ a cors middleware on the server side establish the how and what origins are allowed.